# SelectField to display a string different from the value

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm working on a project that uses react and redux.

I want my `SelectField` to display a string to the users but to select the id value when an option is selected.

I'm using `material-ui 0.19.3v` and got a `SelectField` to display a list of user to choose from linke here:

```
<SelectField
    value={this.props.the_user}
    onChange={(e, i, value) => this.props.setUser(value)}>
    <MenuItem value="" primaryText="" />
    {
        this.state.users.map(x =>
        <MenuItem
            key={`${x.id}MenuItem`}
            value={x}
            primaryText={x.name}
        />)
    }
</SelectField>
```

In `this.props` I got

- `the_user` object that contains all the user informations like name, id, age...
- `users` a list of `user` objects that contains name, id, age...

But my problem is that when the initial redux state is loaded the SelectField is blank though `the_user` is a valid object and I don't know which is the correct way of doing this. Need an advice.

Comment: try to call the action in componentDidMount and have the origin state of the prop in the action as [] and in javascript you can map over [] and then in the componentDidMount when the data is in it should give you the proper dropdown..Lemme know if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the actual value instead of the object like

```
<SelectField
    value={this.props.the_user} //Set the_user as user's id instead of object
    onChange={(e, i, value) => this.props.setUser(value)}>
    <MenuItem value="" primaryText="" />
    {
        this.state.users.map(x =>
        <MenuItem
            key={`${x.id}MenuItem`}
            value={x.id} //here use the id so its type matches the default value supplied to Select field
            primaryText={x.name}
        />)
    }
</SelectField>
```

And in your state just store the string of the id of the user in `the_user`

Comment: In the initial state `the_user` is an object, with this solution it became a string with the id of the user and the name in the SelectField is not displayed anymore

Comment: can you post your setUser function here if thats what setting the state, What you have to do is check which user has that id and then set that user object as your state.

Comment: or What you can do is just forget about the object and just pass the id (I'll make this edit in my answer)

Comment: @lellefood If you are not using the user object anywhere else you can do what i just wrote in the edit and comment , just set the initial state as an id and use that instead of the whole object

Comment: @lellefood oh you edited my answer, haha 
I think you should add those things to your question.

Comment: Lol yes, my bad. Reject it. I solved this, in a minute posting a comment with the description take the best answer for now.

Comment: I get this error: ```Warning: React does not recognize the `primaryText` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `primarytext` instead``` so I guess it is better to use lowecase primarytext